# Azure Logic App is not displaying Functions When Show Azure Functions in the same region selected

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-functions

I Created a function App with BlobTriggerCSharp and this is the name of the function: **BlobTriggerCSharp1**

I want to use this function inside a logic app, so i created logic app and Selected Recurrence, Provided Frequency and Interval. I clicked on Action, Selected **Show Azure Functions in the same region**, It is displaying all the function apps like "Container:FunctionappName", but when i clicked on that existing functions inside that function app is not displaying. Could any one help on this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8e2cd4aa-d944-41ba-8351-53a3c71c0735/azure-logic-app-is-not-displaying-functions-when-show-azure-functions-in-the-same-region-selected?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview. Please avoid posting identical questions in different forums without cross reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want Logic Apps to be able to call your Functions, you need to use a Function with a HTTP WebHook trigger with the WebHook type set to "Generic JSON". Only then will the Logic Apps UX discover the function.