# Getting Logic Apps to recognize Functions from precompiled assemblies?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Function App in C# that I precompile and deploy to Azure using VSTS. I am successfully deploying and can test my 2 HTTP triggers from postman and the command line.

I am now trying to use these Functions in a Logic App. When I go to create a Function action, I select my Function App but it does not recognize my 2 Functions.

Selecting the onsite-functions app should show my 2 Functions.
[image: Select onsite-functions]

But instead, it prompts me to create a Function.
[image: Create Function Screen]

I have created an OpenAPI spec for this Function App, but this does not help. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get my Functions showing up in the Logic App designer?

## Update

Switching from a Kudu deployment to an Azure App Service Deploy step seems to fix the issue.

Comment: checkout the answer to similar question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301379/azure-logic-app-is-not-displaying-functions-when-show-azure-functions-in-the-sam

Comment: Do your functions show up if you go to the Function App UI?

Comment: @TusharJ As far as the similar question goes, the answer provided does not fix the issue. In my question the tslr-decoder app is the same code and setup but done throught the portal instead of VSTS. It works that way.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Yes the functions show up in the App UI. They are read only because of the automated deployment. And as posted in the original question, they run when called via command line.

Comment: @KevinBenton strange, I tried it and don't see this behavior. My VS deployed functions do show up in Logic Apps. Try going to https://{yourapp}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/functions. Do they show up there?

Comment: Yes they do show up.

Comment: Can you try again and see if you could repro it? This looks like a transient thing.